# GridView Drag and Drop not updating on a SqlDataSource

Tags: drag-and-drop, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to add in a drag drop functionality to a devexpress aspx grid, the link below is the Devexpress supplied example code which I used. Copying this code perfectly leads to a website which works perfectly but for some reason, which I cannot really understand, when you change the datasource from an AccessDataSource to an SqlDataSource, the code stops working perfectly. I believe it might be because the grid hasn't loaded the data before the init runs for the grid, which leaves the Dictionary count equal to 0. And I think that is the reason nothing else works from there forward.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4582

this is what replaces the normal Devexpress AccessDataSource, its nothing fancy but it breaks the entire drag drop functionality. Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource   ID="AspqlDataSource1"
                     runat="server"
                     ConnectionString="server name; catalog; id; pass"
                     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM aTable">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDataSource` does not breaks the entire drag drop functionality. Just make sure that you have the `RowOrder` column in your `Grid`:

```html
<dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="RowOrder" Caption=" " VisibleIndex="0" UnboundType="Integer"
    SortIndex="0" SortOrder="Ascending">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <div class="draggable">
            <img src="Images/drag.jpg" />
            <input type="hidden" value='<%# Container.KeyValue %>' />
        </div>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: I literally just changed the datasource and after that, it stopped working. In the SQL Table, I do have a column for RowOrder and it is setup right. So the only difference between working and not working is AccessDataSource and SQLDataSource

Comment: @5tar-Kaster You need to delete `RowOrder` column from your SQL Table because this column is unbound. I made the same changes with `DataSource` and its working.

Comment: that seems to be a good point... but how can I then store the RowOrder so it will be the same on all PCs without it being in the database?

Comment: @5tar-Kaster This question is not related to the original one. If you want to change from AccessDataSource to SQLDataSource then it does not breaks functionality. If you want to change from unbound column to bound column then it breaks functionality. For bound column you must fill `Dictionary` with values as you can see in `gvProducts_CustomUnboundColumnData` method and update column values in `gvProducts_CustomCallback` method.